# Clear Interval not working ( Tried all other answers )

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have this function to check when a opponent is connected. Everything works, except the clearInterval thing... I tried adding window.setInterval and window.clearInterval . I tried adding self. too...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var waitForOpponent = setInterval(checkUserStatus, 2000);

    function checkUserStatus() {
    $('#user').load('checkuser.php?randval='+ Math.random());
        $("#user").ajaxStop(function(){
       if(document.getElementById("user").innerHTML!=""){
                clearInterval(waitForOpponent);
        opponentConnected();
       }
    });
    }

});
```

I also tried to go like this:

```
var waitForOpponent;

function check() { waitForOpponent = setInterval(checkUserStatus, 2000); }

check();
```

Please help me out guys.. I tried everything...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of `ajaxStop` and use the success callback of the `.load`.

```
$('#user').load('checkuser.php?randval='+ Math.random(),function(){
    if(document.getElementById("user").innerHTML!=""){
        clearInterval(waitForOpponent);
        opponentConnected();
    }
});
```

if the requests are taking longer than 2 seconds, ajaxstop will never be called.

A better alternative in my opinion is to not use setInterval:

```
function checkUserStatus() {
    $('#user').load('checkuser.php?randval='+ Math.random(),function(){
        if(document.getElementById("user").innerHTML!=""){
            opponentConnected();
            return; // exit
        }
        setTimeout(checkUserStatus,2000); // continue after 2 seconds
    });
}
checkUserStatus(); // start it up
```

this prevents the ajax requests from piling up on slow connections or on timeouts.

Comment: Thanks for the quickest answer EVER! By the way .ajaxStop was loading, because opponentConnected() was being called ( endlessly , of course ). But nevertheless I used the second solution and it's working perfectly! Thanks!